# julia type unstable when accessing field from abstract type

Tags: polymorphism, julia, multiple-dispatch

I have a question about type instability when accessing the fields of an
`abstract type` (in julia v0.6).

Suppose I have a type hierarchy, all of which share the same instance variable.
I know that it is both type-unstable and not-guaranteed to be correct to access
the field correctly, since someone could always define a new subtype that lacks
the expected variable. However, even when wrapping the member access in a
function, the access is still type unstable, and I can't figure out why.

Assume we have a simple type hierarchy:

```
julia> begin
       abstract type AT end
       mutable struct T1 <: AT
         x::Int
       end
       mutable struct T2 <: AT
         x::Int
       end
       end
```

Instead of accessing `a.x` directly, we wrap it in a function barrier:

```
julia> getX(a::AT)::Int = a.x
>> getX (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype getX(T1(1))
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  a::T1

Body:
  begin
      return (Core.getfield)(a::T1, :x)::Int64
  end::Int64
```

Note that the access through this method is type-stable, since it can infer the
type of `a` to be `T1`.

However, when I use `getX` in a context where the compiler can't know the type
of the variable ahead-of-time, it's still type-unstable:

```
julia> foo() = getX(rand([T1(1),T2(2)]))
>> foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype foo()
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  T <optimized out>

Body:
  begin
      SSAValue(0) = (Core.tuple)($(Expr(:new, :(Main.T1), 1)), $(Expr(:new, :(Main.T2), 2)))::Tuple{T1,T2}
      SSAValue(2) = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for rand(::Array{AT,1}), :(Main.rand), :($(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for copy!(::Array{AT,1}, ::Tuple{T1,T2}), :(Base.copy!), :($(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{AT,1}, svec(Any, Int64), Array{AT,1}, 0, 2, 0))), SSAValue(0))))))
      return (Core.typeassert)((Base.convert)(Main.Int, (Core.getfield)(SSAValue(2), :x)::Any)::Any, Main.Int)::Int64
  end::Int64
```

Note that it inlined the body of `getX`, and replaced it with essentially
`tmp.x::Int64`. This surprises me, since I was expecting `getX` to dispatch to
one of the two instantiations of the same definition we saw above, where no assert
is necessary since the type is known.

---

I thought that this does make some sense if `getX` is *actually* only defined
for the abstract base type `AT` -- there would be no methods to dispatch to in
the way I'm imagining. So I tried redefining `getX` such that it would generate
a specific method for each subtype as follows:

```
julia> getX(a::T where T<:AT)::Int = a.x
>> getX (generic function with 1 method)
```

But that is actually an identical definition, and nothing changed:

```
julia> methods(getX)
>> # 1 method for generic function "getX":
getX(a::AT) in Main at none:1
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: `getX` is type stable, and you don't need the type assertion. But `rand([T1(1),T2(2)])` is _not_ type stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `getX` to take subtypes of `AT` then you have type stable code for `foo`:

```
julia> function getX(a::T)::Int where T <: AT
           a.x
       end
getX (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo() = getX(rand([T1(1),T2(2)]))
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype foo()
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  T <optimized out>

Body:
  begin
      SSAValue(0) = (Core.tuple)($(Expr(:new, :(Main.T1), 1)), $(Expr(:new, :(Main.T2), 2)))::Tuple{T1,T2}
      return (Main.getX)($(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for rand(::Array{AT,1}), :(Main.rand), :($(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for copy!(::Array{AT,1}, ::Tuple{T1,T2}), :(Base.copy!), :($(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{AT,1}, svec(Any, Int64), Array{AT,1}, 0, 2, 0))), SSAValue(0)))))))::Int64
  end::Int64
```

I'm not sure why this, maybe someone with more knowledge on the matter will shed some light on it.
Also, this is only type-stable because `getX` is guaranteed to return an `Int`. If you didn't force `getX` to do this, you wouldn't be guaranteed to return an `Int` as you might have different `AT` subtypes that hold non-Ints.

Comment: Yes you are right, this definitely fixes my problem. And it is more reliable even than manually defining each method, which stops working after 5+ types...

So basically my problem was just that I wrote `getX(a::T where T<:AT)::Int` instead of `getX(a::T)::Int where T <: AT`... What is the difference between those? And why does the second one only work with `function ... end` instead of the simpler `f(x) = y` syntax?

Comment: You could do it as a one-liner: `getX(a::T) where {T <: AT} = a.x::Int`. As for why this works and the other not, I'm not 100% sure and I don't want to just guess. It might be worth referencing the question on the Julia slack or Discourse.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for that. I forgot about the brackets syntax. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so I needed to manually define the different versions of `getX` myself.

---

I was mixing up `julia`'s type dispatch mechanism with `C++`'s template
instantiation. I think I *incorrectly imagined* that `julia` defines a new version of
`getX` for every `T` it's invoked with, in the same way as the C++ template
mechanism.

In this case, I was almost correct when I said

> I was expecting `getX` to dispatch to one of the two instantiations [...]
>   where no assert is necessary since the type is known.

However, in this case, there aren't actually two different methods to
dispatch to -- there's only one. If I actually *define* the two different
methods, the dispatch mechanism can satisfy the type stability:

```
julia> begin
       abstract type AT end
       mutable struct T1 <: AT
         x::Int
       end
       mutable struct T2 <: AT
         x::Int
       end
       end

julia> getX(a::T1) = a.x
>> getX (generic function with 1 method)

julia> getX(a::T2) = a.x
>> getX (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> foo() = getX(rand([T1(1),T2(2)]))
>> foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype foo()
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  T <optimized out>

Body:
  begin
      SSAValue(0) = (Core.tuple)($(Expr(:new, :(Main.T1), 1)), $(Expr(:new, :(Main.T2), 2)))::Tuple{T1,T2
}
      return (Main.getX)($(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for rand(::Array{AT,1}), :(Main.rand), :($(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for copy!(::Array{AT,1}, ::Tuple{T1,T2}), :(Base.copy!), :($(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{AT,1}, svec(Any, Int64), Array{AT,1}, 0, 2, 0))), SSAValue(0)))))))::Int64
  end::Int64
```

I found the inspiration for fixing this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223936/751061

Comment: Although, interestingly, it seems that if the number of types+methods for `getX` hits 5 or more, it goes back to type unstable again. :( Perhaps there's some hard-coded value in there that it can do the calculation for 4 or fewer types but not for more than that?