# Julia Typing/Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, julia, subtyping

Note: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40204956/13147242) and read this part of Julia's [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/), but I couldn't figure it out yet. Therefore, I wrote this post.

Suppose we have the following two structs:

```
struct A
    x
end

struct B
    x
    y
end
```

whereby `A` is a generalization of `B`. Therefore, in other languages like Python or C++ I would make `B` inherit from `A`. Unfortunately, in Julia there is no inheritance, from my understanding so far. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

#### My Understanding About Abstract Types & Sybtyping in Julia, so far:

I just read about the concept of abstract types and subtyping in Julia. So far I've understood that I could do the following:

```
abstract type C end

struct A <: C
    x
end

struct B <: C
    x
    y
end
```

Hence, `A` and `B` are subtypes of `C` and the following holds:

```
(A <: C) == true
(B <: C) == true
(A <: B) == false
(B <: A) == false
```

Thus, I can't assign an instance of `B` to a variable of type `A` and vise versa.

#### Question:

Consider the first code example. Is it possible to make `B` "inherit" from `A` and to not define the field `x` in `B` again? Like I'd expect it from inheritance in other languages.

I hope my problem/question is clear, otherwise, please ask! Thanks for any hint/comment in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Like I'd expect it from inheritance in other languages.

No, it is not possible. Additionally, it is an intended design choice.

In general in Julia the design follows [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle.

Therefore if you indeed want to use `A` in `B` then typically you would do:

```
struct B
    a::A
    y
end
```

An alternative is to use an abstract upper type as you defined it:

```
abstract type C end

struct A <: C
    x
end

struct B <: C
    x
    y
end
```

And define an interface for `C` that requires all its subtypes to define `x` field, eg. like this:

```
getx(::C) = throw(ArgumentError("subtypes of C must define getter of x"))
getx(a::A) = a.x
getx(b::b) = b.x
```

In your simple case you also could just leave out defining anything, as the following code:

```
f(c::C) = typeof(c.x)
```

will work just fine (as long as all subtypes of `C` define property `x` - which should be clearly stated in the documentation of `C` that it is required).